# Page.ResolveClientUrl in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am stuck in a situation where i want to use HTML page instead of using .aspx page for some performance reason, here i am using aspx page just because of css path and javascipt files path like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/files/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js") %>'></script>
```

so it appends the root directory name before the path like this on dev server
**/filemanagement/files/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js**
and on local it look like **/files/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js**

Here my question is if I want to use a HTML page, and in HTML we can't write  **src='<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/files/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js") Page.ResolveClienURLL**, is there any way in JavaScript or jQuery we can achive the same approach?

Answer (score -3):

This will return the root directory name if exists otherwise it will return empty string.

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: Please try to run it once. it works 100%, This is what i was looking for.

Comment: I am calling an aspx page in popup and the popup will always use root directory page , this is the reason it is working for me.